# Security Warning Window in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to download file from Internet Explorer 8 and I am using the following URL

```
http://servername:8080/apps/controller?getfile=test.xls
```

I am getting Security Warning window when I click URL, what could be the reason for this and how can I resolve this issue? In Chrome this works fine.

Any help is highly appreciable

Comment: Are you asking why IE is behaving the way it does?

Comment: @DaveRook Yes and are there any ways it could be worked around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `http://servername:8080` to the trusted sites.

internet explorer -> internet option -> security -> trusted sites -> sites